# Removing item from array not working

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to remove a tag from an array. But I can't get it to work – nothing happens. The console.log output seems to be correct. Thanks!

**The event handler**

```
Template.doc.events({
    'click .remove': function(event, template) {
        console.log("This doc's _id: " + template.data._id);
        console.log("doc's tags: " + template.data.metadata.tags);

        var thisTag = this;
        console.log("thisTag: " + thisTag);

        MyPix.update (
            template.data._id,
            { $pull: { 'template.data.metadata.tags': thisTag }},
            { multi: true }
        );
    },
});
```

**The Template**

```
<template name="doc">
    <ol><li>
        <span class="property">metadata.tags</span>: 
        {{#each this.metadata.tags}}
            <span class="tag"><span class="remove">X</  span>{{this}}</span>
        {{/each}}
    </li></ol>
</template>
```

Comment: put a sample document if its possible

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, it looks like your field-identifier inside the pull is incorrect. Here you have to use the MongoDB identifier, not the one belonging to your object.Try changing

```
template.data.metadata.tags
```

To

```
metadata.tags
```

inside the pull call.

Comment: Thanks @Mellowlicious but that doesn't work either: `Error: documentMatches needs a document`. I've been trying all kind of combinations but nothing seems to work. At least I'm getting no errors in the console with the original code above – but it does not remove anything.

Answer (score 1):

Try with the [$push](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#up._S_push) operator.

```
Template.doc.events({
    'click .remove': function(event, template) {
        console.log("This doc's _id: " + template.data._id);
        console.log("doc's tags: " + template.data.metadata.tags);

        var thisTag = this;
        console.log("thisTag: " + thisTag);

        MyPix.update (
            template.data._id,
            { $push: { 'template.data.metadata.tags': thisTag }},
            { multi: true }
        );
    },
});
```

if you `console.log(template.data.metadata.tags)` what did you get an array?
`console.log(template.data.metadata.tags.length)` what return?

You may wanna take a look into the [Array Update Operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update-array/)

Comment: With the push operator I get a new `Object` (which is an array) added to the array. @Ethaan

Comment: And when you console.log the template.data did you get an array? Im looking on the other comment and seems like you dont have an array

Comment: Also the tag are other array to? Did you try with $in?

Comment: a new `[object Object]` is added to the array when adding `this` via $push. So it seems as if `this` is not a string but an object. Maybe that's the reason? Because those objects can successfully be removed via `$pull` later. Might it be that `this` needs and additional handle? Also, I'm not sure how to use `$in` in this context.

Comment: Yes try with this.tags or something

Comment: this is it: `var thisTag = String(this);` – thanks @Ethaan – And the $pull line will work as this: `{ $pull: { 'metadata.tags': thisTag }},`– thanks @Mellowlicious

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like, maybe?

```
MyPix.update (
        template.data._id,
        { $pull: { metadata:{ tags: thisTag } } },
        { multi: true }
    );
```

Comment: Sorry but this does not work either :(  `update failed: MongoError: Cannot apply $pull/$pullAll modifier to non-array`

Comment: so I assume your tags aren't stored in an array?

Comment: This is a copy/paste from the FS.File document in the console: `tags: Array[6]0: "sprite"1: "ecity"2: "crocodile"3: "animal"4: "vehicle"5: "test"length: 6` (no spaces added or removed). Tags seem to be an array.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that `this` is an object and has to be converted to a string. And the MongoDB identifier has to be used with `$pull`. Thanks for the pointers! @Ethaan & @Mellowlicious

```
'click .remove': function(event, template) {
    console.log("This doc's _id: " + template.data._id);
    console.log("doc's tags: " + template.data.metadata.tags);

    var thisTag = String(this); // conversion to a string
    console.log("removing thisTag: " + thisTag);

    MyPix.update (
        template.data._id,
        { $pull: { 'metadata.tags': thisTag }}, // MongoDB identifier
    );
}
```

Comment: `{multi: true}` doesn't make sense when you are only ever updating one document.